# Can the processor of an Acer Aspire XC-704 PC be replaced?

Tags: cpu

Is it possible to open up an [Acer Aspire XC-704](http://www.acer.com/ac/en/GB/content/model/DT.SZLEK.011) and upgrade the components like the processor from intel celeron to i3 or i5?

Comment: The proper question is, "Can the motherboard handle a processor upgrade?"  The model of the computer could possibly have several different components used in it.  Can you post the MoBo type and model?

Comment: Yes—it is socket LGA 1150. Any *Haswell* desktop processor that fits that socket may be installed, up to and including the i7-4790K, but be sure you can satisfy cooling and power requirements.

Comment: Just because it fits the socket does not mean the bios will support it.